# Pairing a root with the half-sum of positive roots

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\frak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional complex simple Lie algebra together with a choice of Cartan subalgebra and associated root system $(\Delta, (-,-))$. Also we denote the half-sum of positive roots by
$$
\rho := \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha \in \Delta_+} \alpha.
$$
What can one say about the scalar
$$
(\alpha,\rho)?
$$
I feel this is an easy question (perhaps too easy for M.O.) but I also feel I am missing a simple trick to produce the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, my original answer was about the expansion of the *highest root* $\theta$ into the fundamental weights $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n$. For the Weyl vector $\rho$, something much simpler is true: we have $\rho=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \omega_i$. It is easy to see this since the simple reflection $s_{\alpha_i}$ sends $\alpha_i$ to $-\alpha_i$, while permuting the other positive roots.

A precise reference for this fact is Proposition 29 of $\S$1.10 of Chapter VI (Root Systems) of Bourbaki's book on Lie Groups and Lie Algebras.

**EDIT**: As requested by LSpice in the comments, let me restore (and correct) my comments about the expansion of the highest root $\theta$ into fundamental weights. We have $\theta=\sum_{i}c_i\omega_i$ where $c_i$ is the number of edges from the special "affine" node $0$ in the extended Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak{g}$ to the node $i$. (For the simply laced case there is no ambiguity regarding what is meant by extended Dynkin diagram; for non-simply laced cases there are two different versions of the "extended Dynkin diagram" and they give the fundamental weight coefficients for the highest root and highest short root, respectively.)

I'm fairly certain this statement about $\theta$ appears somewhere in Bourbaki as well, but I'm having trouble locating precisely where.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I didn't know how I didn't know about this formula! Is it easy to see why this is true?

Comment: @DidierdeMontblazon: Apologies, see my edit. I was confusing $\theta$ and $\rho$. The coefficients for $\rho$ are all $1$.

Comment: Sure, got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry but now I realize I don't get your comment. What does the action of the Weyl group help us to re-express $\rho$?

Comment: @DidierdeMontblazon, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445763/pairing-a-root-with-the-half-sum-of-positive-roots#comment1151337_445765), $s_i$ sends $2\rho$ to $\sum_{j \ne i} \alpha_j - \alpha_i = \sum_j \alpha_j - 2\alpha_i = 2\rho - 2\alpha_i$ (not because it fixes the $\alpha_j$ with $j \ne i$, but because it permutes them); but it also sends $2\rho$ to $2\rho - 2(\alpha_i, \rho)\alpha_i$.  Therefore, $(\alpha_i, \rho) = 1$.  Since $i$ was arbitrary and $(\alpha_i, \rho)$ is the coefficient of $\omega_i$ in $\rho$, the result follows.

Comment: Your original answer for the highest root was also interesting, and I didn't know it.  Would you consider restoring it, say after the correct answer, with a note that it is an answer to a different question?

Comment: @LSpice: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Sorry for being obtuse, but why does $s_i$ send  $2\rho$ to $2\rho - 2(\alpha_i,\rho)\alpha_i$?

Comment: @DidierdeMontblazon This is the definition of $s_i$ (and in fact the formula for a reflection in any vector space): The reflection through $v$ sends $w$ to $w - 2( w,v) v / (v,v)$.

Comment: @Will: OF COURSE! Thanks very much! Unfortunately I now feel quite stupid.

Comment: @DidierdeMontblazon, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445763/pairing-a-root-with-the-half-sum-of-positive-roots/445765#comment1151344_445765), sorry for being obtuse, but that's the kind of angle that simple roots make? 

Comment: @LSpice: Very nice :)

Comment: @LSpice: Okay, I restored the comments about the highest root $\theta$ and extended Dynkin diagram. I also found a reference for the basic facts about $\rho$ (but unfortunately not what I wrote about $\theta$).

Comment: [Thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1151349)!  Isn't the statement you adduce nearly the definition?  I would expect the definition of the extended Dynkin diagram to be that the number of edges joining $0$, which I call $-\theta$, to $\alpha_i$ to be $-(-\theta, \alpha_i) = (\theta, \alpha_i)$. \\ Also, I have never seen two meanings of the extended Dynkin diagram.  Is the "other" meaning just that you use the negative of the highest short root rather than the negative of the highest root, and otherwise proceed as in the "usual" extended case?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's right, you could simply view this as the definition of extended Dynkin diagram (and yes, to get the two versions in the non-simply laced cases you take either the highest root or highest short root: the point is these are the only roots in the fundamental chamber).

Answer (score 5):

Sorry but I have to quibble: $(\alpha,\rho)$ isn't canonical, it depends on the choice of $W$-invariant inner product. What *is* canonical is $\langle \alpha^\vee,\rho\rangle$ where $\alpha^\vee$ is a coroot and $\langle,\rangle$ is the canonical pairing between roots and coroots. (IMHO it is always better to pair roots with coroots, as in Bourbaki, not roots with roots.)

Anyway as per the preceding discussion, $\langle\alpha^\vee,\rho\rangle=1$ for $\alpha$ a simple root; therefore $\langle\alpha^\vee,\rho\rangle=\operatorname{height}(\alpha)$ for any root; and this is equal to the Coxeter number minus 1 (the sum of the labels on the Dynkin diagram) for the highest root.